# MySQL How to create one to Zero or Many relation

Tags: mysql, cardinality

i have entity customer and entity order, a customer can have 0 or more orders but an order can only have 1 customer.

I already tried a lot of things like making the foreign key unchecked at NN but I cant get a foreign key order at customer

EDIT: Using mySQL ERD workbench

Comment: making the foreign key unchecked at NN - I have no idea what this means. Are you using a ui of some sort (phpmayadmin, mysqlworkbench etc)?

Comment: added it @P.Salmon

Comment: A foreign key should be in the orders table referencing customer.

Comment: But when that happens the ' ZERO ' relation will be at the customer side, but it has to be at the order side

Comment: @StanlyGoodLife What's wrong with that? A customer can have 0 orders, but an order has to have one customer, surely?

Comment: @benM as far as my understanding of an ERD goes, if the 0 is at the side of the customer doesnt that men that an order has 0 customers? which obviously is incorrect

Comment: @StanlyGoodLife, no. Check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDzeI.jpg (in particular notice the 0-or-many against the order entity).

Comment: @benM yes, that picture is exactly what I want to achieve, but if I do as said the 0 will be on the customer side, and just like in your example it has to be on the order side

Comment: It would have been better question  if you had mentioned that you were using mysqlworkbench's ERD tool -

Comment: No. It wouldn’t, because you’re enforcing checks on the foreign key so that an order cannot have a 0 customer relationship. See the answer posted by O. Jones.

Comment: @benM, yes I understand exactly how it works yaknow, the picture you linked me is what I am trying to create, 1 relationship at CUSTOMER side and 0 or MANY at ORDER side but I just cant seem to create that in mysql erd workbench, It automatically places the 0 at CUSTOMER side

Comment: My question is just, HOW do I make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `customer` table will have a unique `customer_id` column. In the MySQL world we often use autoincrementing primary keys for this kind of `id` column.

Your `order` table will have a `customer_id` column that's a foreign key to `customer.customer_id`.

This allows the `order` table to have any number of rows relating to a particular `customer_id`: none, one, or many. The foreign key relationship, when enforced--checked--simply prevents an `order` from having a `customer_id` value that references no valid customer.

Classic data design tools with their distinction between logical and physical design can drive ya nuts when you're trying to do easy stuff like this.

**Pro tip** if you name your `id` columns the same way everywhere they're used, data design tools tend to work better, especially when "reverse-engineering" your tables. That's why I suggested column names like `customer.customer_id` and `order.customer_id` rather than `customer.id` and `order.customer_id`.

Comment: Yes it is quite easy, as the picture posted by @benM, that is exactly what I want, I understand how the ERD works but I just cant seem to get the 0 relationship on the SIDE OF ORDER it automatically goes to the side of CUSTOMER in mySQL erd workbench, but it should obviously be on the order side